# Socket соединение без заморозки основного потока

Tags: c#

Использую пример от майков

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

Но при ожиданий подключения блочиться основной поток и программа просто ждет подключения - нужно вынести в отдельный поток?

Comment: Да, выносите в отдельный поток

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вынес - теперь вообще не запускается new Thread(new ThreadStart(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening));

Comment: Значит, вынесли не так.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да вроде так выносил раньше

Comment: А что будет происходить в основном потоке?

Comment: @B. Vandyshev подключение игроков

Comment: Попробуйте асинхронно запустить через Task.Run(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening)

Answer (score 0):

[ANetwork - самописное сетевое ядро на асинхронных сокетах](https://yadi.sk/d/rbVR6B_C3QqK52)

[Ручные тесты для "понимания" логики работы](https://yadi.sk/d/Pa86pPZC3QqKNG)

PS.
В асинхронных сокетах, есть подводные камни, на которые я уже натыкался и сгладил все большинство острых моментов. Особенно сэкономит вам время если вы разрабатываете сетевое ядро для какой-нибудь небольшой игры. (Данная либа спокойно держит 10к+ подключений на средней машине)